# gvfs on debian with openbox?

Tags: linux, debian, openbox, gvfs

is it possible to use gvfs on a debian system that only has openbox?  
here's some info about my sys:

`sudo cat /etc/debian_version`

12.5

`sudo cat /etc/os-release`

HOME_URL="https://www.bunsenlabs.org"
ID="bunsenlabs"
ID_LIKE="debian"
NAME="BunsenLabs GNU/Linux"
PRETTY_NAME="BunsenLabs GNU/Linux 12 (Boron)"
SUPPORT_URL="https://forums.bunsenlabs.org"
VERSION="12 (Boron)"
VERSION_ID="12"
VERSION_CODENAME="boron"